# Can use a variable, even though it doesn't have an owner

Tags: rust

Why does the following rust code work?

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = Some(vec![1, 2, 3]);

    let b = &a.unwrap(); // .unwrap() takes ownership of the Option<Vec<i32>>

    dbg!(b); // Why can I do this? a is no longer the owner of Some(vec![1, 2, 3]), and should've been dropped.
    // Who owns Some(vec![1, 2, 3])?
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue, you're using `b`, that take the value inside `a`. Even `a` is not longer accessible as the value is moved, you can still access the moved value on `b`.

Comment: @MarioSantini But b doesn't own the Vec, only the reference to it

Comment: No, the value it's moved, so the vec now is owned by b.

Comment: @MarioSantini No, `b` is a reference. A reference borrows a value, it does not own it.

Comment: Sorry, my sentence: "the vec is owned by b" is wrong, but it does not change the result, as the value unwrapped should live long enought to be a valid reference until the main function exits.